# Unable to correctly construct WHERE in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I can't seem to successfully recreate a simple WHERE statement in LINQ. My result set would not filter until there are at least 2 conditions.

The WHERE statement that I'm trying to recreate looks like this

```
WHERE ID = @ID OR Email LIKE @Email OR ScreenName LIKE @ScreenName
```

Now my LINQ looks like this

```
 ApplicationData.UserList.Where(u => u.Id == userId || 
                                     u.Email.Contains(email) || 
                                     u.ScreenName.Contains(screenName)).ToList();
```

Should be pretty straight forward. Can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does it really look like that in SQL? `Email LIKE @ID` ? Also note that if `email` contains `%`, then `.Contains(...)` might not do what you think it does.

Comment: I typed it how I typed it assuming that it will be understood that they are parameterized. And the Email LIKE @ID was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @AndrewLiao you can try to use [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Contains`

Comment: @AndrewLiao why you want use `LIKE` instead of `equals(=)`?

Comment: @Grundy I'll try out SqlMethods.Like later. Thanks for the suggestion!
I'm using GUID's so I need them to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Should

```
u.Email.Contains(email)
```

not be

```
u.Email.Contains(userId.ToString())
```

Because the original query uses @ID for this.

Comment: Ooops sorry. Should have been Email LIKE @Email. Updated

Comment: So if your LINQ uses `Contains` then this assumes in your SQL you must have been passing values such as "%something%" as @Email. Otherwise your LINQ might require `StartsWith` or `EndsWith` or just plain `Equals`

Comment: Yes, my expected value is is "%something%".

Comment: So are you stripping the % out in your LINQ version?

Comment: No. That is why I'm using Contains. As if my understanding, Contains() runs like %something%

Comment: Yes, but the % have no special meaning, they would be taken as literal characters.  So unless you have emails that actually contain the string "%something%" then nothing is going to match.